# Enabling authentication for Kapacitor breaks Chronograf

Tags: authentication, influxdb, kapacitor, chronograf

I just installed the entire TICK stack, but I ran into a silly issue.

When I leave influx with auth_enabled = false, I can get Telegraf to talk to Influx and Chronograf works perfectly.

Then, I changed auth_enabled to true and set a username and password in my influx config. If I update the Telegraf and Kapacitor config files with the authentication details - they work perfectly. The problem is the Chronograf now laughs at me (so rude) and tells me that it can’t connect to influx.

You can see the log below for the exact error. Am I missing something crucial when it comes to configuring chronograf? Why won’t it connect to influx when the other two apps are both happy to work?

Any help would seriously be appreciated…

Oh, btw. I’m one of those silly people that are running all of this on Windows… if that makes any difference.

```
time="2020-01-22T11:36:06+02:00" level=info msg="Response: OK" component=server method=GET remote_addr="[::1]:62574" response_time=0s status=200
time="2020-01-22T11:36:16+02:00" level=info msg="Response: OK" component=server method=GET remote_addr="[::1]:62574" response_time=0s status=200
time="2020-01-22T11:36:20+02:00" level=info msg="Failed to retrieve database version" error="{\"error\":\"unable to parse authentication credentials\"}\n"
time="2020-01-22T11:36:20+02:00" level=error msg="Error message Error contacting source" component=server http_status =400
time="2020-01-22T11:36:20+02:00" level=info msg="Response: Bad Request" component=server method=POST remote_addr="[::1]:62574" response_time=4.9858ms status=400
time="2020-01-22T11:36:26+02:00" level=info msg="Response: OK" component=server method=GET remote_addr="[::1]:62574" response_time=0s status=200
```

Answer (score 0):

After enabling authentication on InfluxDB, you mention that you update Telegraf and Kapacitor config files with the required credentials. However, you don't take any action for Chronograf as far as I understand.

When you enable authentication on InfluxDB, you must update the current InfluxDB connection through Chronograf UI > Configuration > Add Connection. Otherwise, it would try to make a connection to the InfluxDB instance using the default anonymous endpoint.

[image]

Comment: Sorry @kahveci, I didn't mention that explicitly because it's soooo obvious :) We did actually configure chronograf properly.

Comment: At the moment - we've managed to get chronograf to connect, but now Kapacitor is complaining that it can't talk to influx. Seems like the moment we set ping-auth-enabled = true - chronograf breaks.